# FParsec Not Recognizing a Type’s Constructor

Tags: f#, fparsec

The following top-level XML parser definition returns the error  `The value or constructor ‘TOP_LEVEL_RECORD’ is not defined.` …

```
let xTop_Level, xTop_Level_Ref = createParserForwardedToRef<TOP_LEVEL_RECORD, unit>()

do xTop_Level_Ref := 
    pipe4 
        (opt xDeclaration) 
        (opt (many xComment_or_CData))
        xElement
        (opt (many xComment_or_CData))
        (fun decl before_root root after_root
            -> {Declaration = decl
                Before_Root = before_root
                Root = root
                After_Root = after_root}) |>> TOP_LEVEL_RECORD
// This returns the error -------------------→^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`TOP_LEVEL_RECORD` is defined as …

```
type TOP_LEVEL_RECORD = {Declaration : XDECLARATION option
                         Before_Root : COMMENTS_OR_CDATA list option
                         Root : XELEMENT
                         After_Root : COMMENTS_OR_CDATA list option
                         }
```

The parsers `xDeclaration`, `xCommentor_Cdata`, and `xElement` are all correctly  defined and return the corresponding types in the `TOP_LEVEL_RECORD`.

The `let xTop_Level, xTop_Level_Ref = createParserForwardedToRef<TOP_LEVEL_RECORD, unit>()` is Fparsec’s syntax for recursive parser calls documented here: http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#parsing-json.createParserForwardedToRef-example.

If I define the type `type TOP_LEVEL = TOP_LEVEL_TYPE of TOP_LEVEL_RECORD` and replace `TOP_LEVEL_RECORD` with `TOP_LEVEL` and `TOP_LEVEL_TYPE` as follows …

```
let xTop_Level, xTop_Level_Ref = createParserForwardedToRef<TOP_LEVEL, unit>()
// Replaced this text ------------------------------------->^^^^^^^^^

do xTop_Level_Ref := 
    pipe4 
        (opt xDeclaration) 
        (opt (many xComment_or_CData))
        xElement
        (opt (many xComment_or_CData))
        (fun decl before_root root after_root
            -> {Declaration = decl
                Before_Root = before_root
                Root = root
                After_Root = after_root}) |>> TOP_LEVEL_TYPE
// Replaced this text ----------------------->^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

... the code compiles without any errors or warnings.

Why does `TOP_LEVEL_TYPE` have a constructor here and not `TOP_LEVEL_RECORD`?

Can you point me to the relevant part of the F# or FParsec documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TOP_LEVEL_RECORD` (a record type) and `TOP_LEVEL` (a union type) are type names and cannot be used as constructors.

To construct a `TOP_LEVEL_RECORD` you use the syntax as in your code

```
{ Declaration = decl
  Before_Root = before_root
  Root = root
  After_Root = after_root }
```

To construct an instance of a union type, you use one of the case names as a constructor function; `TOP_LEVEL_TYPE` in your case, since there's only one union case.

Note that in your type definition

```
type TOP_LEVEL = TOP_LEVEL_TYPE of TOP_LEVEL_RECORD
```

`TOP_LEVEL` is a type, but `TOP_LEVEL_TYPE` (despite its name) is not a type, but a constructor function for the `TOP_LEVEL` type.

So record types do not have named constructor functions, but union types do.

For your code, you can just skip the  `|>> TOP_LEVEL_RECORD` part.

You can read about record types and union types in [F# language spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf), sections 8.4 and 8.5.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to that documentation.  I had before only seen the MSFT docs.  But only 8.5 mentions 'union case names' and nowhere that union case names serve as constructor references.  The closest reference to union case names possibly being a constructor label is on page 137, "One CLI static method U.NewCfor each non-null union case C. This method constructs an object for that case."  But that is pretty obscure.  Are there docs directly saying union case names are constructors?  Also my code ```type TOP_LEVEL = TOP_LEVEL_TYPE of TOP_LEVEL_RECORD``` isn't a union case, what is it?

Comment: Your type `TOP_LEVEL` really _is_ a union type, but one with only one case. You can find info on the case names being constructors [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions)

Comment: Thank you.  This distinction between constructor and type name and associated syntactic sugar seems unnecessary.  Couldn't F# tell from  context that a type name is being used as a constructor?  Is there a case where a record constructor might be customized, perhaps to set default values, that would still allow use of the |> operator?